# Objective-C framework documentation comments not shown after export

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, frameworks, javadoc

I'm building a macOS / iOS framework in Objective-C. Most methods have a JavaDoc like documentation which is displayed in the Quick Help section in Xcode properly. However, after I build the framework and want to use it in a different project, the documentation does not show up in the Quick Help section anymore. I know that I could move the documentation from the source file to the header file and that would fix my problem. But, is there any way to keep my documentation in the source file and somehow export it to the header file at build phase? (or anything similar)

Comment: I know you don’t want to hear this, but the documentation for public methods/properties really belongs in the header file.

Comment: I know. But I document every method including private methods. That would either split up my documentation, where public methods are documented in the header file and private methods are documented in the source file. Or, I would need to duplicate the documentation and save it in both files. Keeping both in sync etc. What I would prefer is something like a script that will copy the documentation from source to the header file in the final product. Is that possible? :-) (in a post compilation step?)

Comment: Best practice, IMHO, is to documenting public methods in the header and, where needed, document private methods in the .m files. I would not suggest duplicating documentation (they’ll invariably deviate over time and you’re then faced with the dilemma of which is the right one). And I know of no tool that copies documentation in `.m` files to headers.

Comment: All of this being said, it is possible to generate docsets (and HTML documentation) with third party tools, like [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc). Have you looked at those? The issue with that, IMHO, is that documentation is generally best when you can use it as a resource for what the public interface is, so I personally wouldn’t personally want private methods to be included, because we look at these docs to understand how to use the class in question, and including private methods (whose implementations are subject to change over time) will only confuse the situation.

Comment: I know about appledoc and doxygen and agree that documentation should pop up directly in code. And the private methods should not end up in the end-user documentaion, I only need them during development of the framework itself. I also like the fact that documentation in source files adds to readability. Where in most cases the header is already short and comprehensible. Anyway, I'll see if I can code a build script. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Sorry I couldn’t help. ;)